# Is it confirmed that Mitchell Starc and Chris Lynn will not play In IPL 2018?

Tags: cricket, indian-premier-league

I hear the news that due to Injury, Mitchell Starc and Chris Lynn will not play in current IPL-2018.

Is it confirmed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it seems Chris Lynn will play in IPL 2018.

From [News18 article](https://www.news18.com/cricketnext/news/ipl-2018-chris-lynn-has-a-hit-sunil-naraine-bowls-at-kkr-nets-1706055.html),

> Kolkata: A fit-again Chris Lynn was seen batting in full flow along with Sunil Narine as two-time former champions Kolkata Knight Riders geared up for the Indian Premier League with a practice match at the Eden Gardens.
>
> Having recovered sufficiently from a dislocated shoulder suffered during the recent T20I tri-series against Australia, **Lynn headed to training less than 24 hours** after he joined along with veteran speedster Mitchell Johnson, who opted to rest.
>
> **The docs and the physios are happy so that's all I can do Fingers crossed I can keep going in the right direction. I'm doing everything I can to get back out there**, Lynn had told Cricket Australia.

Whereas Mitchell Starc will not play.

From [News18 article](https://www.news18.com/cricketnext/news/ipl-2018-aussie-pacer-mitchell-starc-to-miss-tournament-due-to-injury-1703765.html),

> "Mitchell Starc has a 'tibial bone stress in his right leg'. He will return home for further assessment after the Test and will miss the IPL," Cricket Australia announced on Twitter.

Here is [that tweet](https://twitter.com/CricketAus/status/979625386500861953).